# Bayesian fit of cosine wave taking longer than expected

Tags: python, statistics, linear-regression, bayesian, markov-chains

In a recent homework, I was asked to perform a Bayesian fit over a set of data *a* and *b* using a Metropolis algorithm.  The relationship between *a* and *b* is given:

> e(t) = e_0*cos(w*t)
>
> w = 2 * pi

The Metropolis algorithm is (it works fine with other fit):

```
def metropolis(logP, args, v0, Nsteps, stepSize):

    vCur = v0
    logPcur = logP(vCur, *args)
    v = []
    Nattempts = 0

    for i in range(Nsteps):
        while(True):
            #Propose step:
            vNext = vCur + stepSize*np.random.randn(*vCur.shape)
            logPnext = logP(vNext, *args)
            Nattempts += 1

            #Accept/reject step:
            Pratio = (1. if logPnext>logPcur else np.exp(logPnext-logPcur))

            if np.random.rand() < Pratio: 
                vCur = vNext
                logPcur = logPnext
                v.append(vCur)
                break

    acceptRatio = Nsteps*(1./Nattempts)
    return np.array(v), acceptRatio
```

I have tried to Bayesian fit the cosine wave and used the Metropolis algorithm above:

```
e_0 = -0.00155 

def strain_t(e_0,t):
    return e_0*np.cos(2*np.pi*t)

data = pd.read_csv('stressStrain.csv')
t = np.array(data['t'])
e = strain_t(e_0,t)

def logfitstrain_t(params,t,e):
    e_0 = params[0]
    sigmaR = params[1]
    strainModel = strain_t(e_0,t)
    return np.sum(-0.5*((e-strainModel)/sigmaR)**2 - np.log(sigmaR))


params0 = np.array([-0.00155,np.std(t)]) 
params, accRatio = metropolis(logfitstrain_t, (t,e), params0, 1000, 0.042)
print('Acceptance ratio:', accRatio)

e0 = np.mean(params[0])
print('e0=',e0)

e_t = e0*np.cos(2*np.pi*t)
sns.jointplot(t, e_t, kind='hex',color='purple')
```

The data in .csv looks like

[image: table with columns "t", "strain", and "stress", with five rows]

There isn't any error message showing after I hit run, but it takes forever for python to give me an output.  **What did I do wrong here?**

Answer (score 1):

#### Why it might *"take forever"*

Your algorithm is designed to run until it *accepts* a given number of proposals (1000 in the example).  Thus, if it's running for a long time, you're likely rejecting a bunch of proposals. This can happen when the step size is too large, leading new proposals to end up in distant, low probability regions of the likelihood space.  **Try reducing your step size.** This may require you to also increase the number of samples to ensure the posterior space becomes adequately explored.

#### A more serious concern

Because you only append **accepted** proposals to the chain `v`, you haven't actually implemented the Metropolis algorithm, and instead obtain a biased set of samples that will tend to overrepresent less likely regions of the posterior space.  A true Metropolis implementation re-appends the previous proposal whenever the new proposal is rejected.  You can still enforce a minimum number of accepted proposals, but you really must append something every time.